# Join three tables using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join

how can I join three table and get all value 
for two table I refer

```
using(Dataclasscontext DbContext = new Dataclasscontext())
{
   var result = (from t1 in DbContext.tbl1 join t2 in DbContext.tbl2 on t1.id equel t2.id select new {t1.id,t1.name,t2.class,t2.std}).toArray();
}
```

and for three table I refer

```
using(Dataclasscontext DbContext = new Dataclasscontext())
{
   var result = (from t1 in DbContext.tbl1 
                 from t2 in DbContext.tbl2 where t1.id1 == t2.id1 
                 from t3 in Db`enter code here`Context.tbl3 where t2.id2 == t3.id2).toArray();
}
```

but don't want this type of query for join three table. is anyone helps me to join three table using join

Comment: the result you are looking for is what kind of join ? Left, Right or Inner ?

Comment: what about var result = _dbContext.tbl1.Include("tbl2").Include("tbl2.tbl3").ToList(); ?

Comment: That's one of the most common smells in EF/LINQ. Trying to treat *entities* as if they were tables and LINQ as a replacement to SQL. They aren't. Create proper relations and navigation properties in your *entities* and EF will generate the joins. All you'll have to do is load the *root entities* and EF will load all the children

Comment: @tzm `Include` doesn't mean join. It won't work if relations aren't already defined.. It's not needed either. If the final `Select` call reads data from the child classes, the proper joins and selections will be generated to return only the necessary data

Comment: @MinhajPatel to put it another way, 1,2 or 5 tables, it doesn't really matter. You can write very similar querie to retrieve the data you want

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so ef "Include" doesn't generate join in raw sql? If not then what it generates?

Comment: @tzm *relations*, specified through navigation properties and collections, using attributes or explicit context configuration. How would `Include` guess which object to load? Which properties would it pick for the join if the relations weren't already defined?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want to do, but i think you want to get rid of the "froms".

Here an Example which uses Linq with "classic-methods" only:

```
// Testclasses which will be joined
public class TestClass1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
}
public class TestClass2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
}

static void Main()
{
    // define some example-data
    List<TestClass1> list1 = new List<TestClass1>()
    {
        new TestClass1() { Id = 1, Name1 = "One1" },
        new TestClass1() { Id = 2, Name1 = "Two1" },
        new TestClass1() { Id = 3, Name1 = "Three1" }
    };
    List<TestClass2> list2 = new List<TestClass2>()
    {
        new TestClass2() { Id = 1, Name2 = "One2" },
        new TestClass2() { Id = 2, Name2 = "Two2" },
        new TestClass2() { Id = 3, Name2 = "Three2" }
    };

    // Here the 'magic' happens:
    // We perform a join one our 1st list
    // We send list2 as list to join with
    // We define two key-selectors in lambda-expressions: t1 => t1.Id and t2 => t2.Id
    // We form the joined object as anonymous type: (t1, t2) => new { Id = t1.Id, Name1 = t1.Name1, Name2 = t2.Name2}
    var joinedList = list1.Join(
        list2,
        t1 => t1.Id,
        t2 => t2.Id,
        (t1, t2) => new { Id = t1.Id, Name1 = t1.Name1, Name2 = t2.Name2 }
        );

    foreach (var item in joinedList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}, Name1: {1}, Name2: {2}", item.Id, item.Name1, item.Name2);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an EF question. Even with LINQ to Objects though using joins is a bad idea. Instead of flat lists, add proper properties and collections to the entities. No need to join, just navigate to the child entities

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Totally correct, but this was not the question. In his example he forms a anonymous object `new {t1.id,t1.name,t2.class,t2.std}`, because of this i have to think that he wants to join.

Comment: no you don't. In fact it's trivial to create an `Item2` property in the `TestClass1` class that points to `TestClass2` and use `Name2=t1.Items.Name` in the `Select()` call. No joins required